# PCLStorage in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-8, portable-class-library

I'm using PCLStorage for a Win8/Wp8 project I'm working on. I'm using it within a PCL itself, and have it referenced in my Win8, Wp8 and PCL projects. Everything is working great in Win8.

In Wp8 however, once I hit my PCL for storage which uses PCLStorage, I'm getting a `NotImpmlementedException` when I call `FileSystem.Current;`

> "This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly.  You should reference the PCLStorage NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation."

But like I said, I have the PCLStorage NuGet package referenced in my Wp8 project AND the PCL project the same way I do in my Win8 project.

Any idea what's happening?

(I should also note that PCLStorage is working fine if I use it in a new Wp8 project)

Answer (score 3):

Try uninstalling the PCLStorage NuGet package from all projects and then reinstalling it in all of them.

If it still doesn't work, try checking the references to the PCLStorage DLLs in the WP8 project and make sure they are coming from the wp8 folder in the package.

If that doesn't lead anywhere, try setting copy local to false in the references from your PCL to the PCL Storage DLLs.  If you have to do that it's an issue that needs to be fixed, so please file a bug for it.

**EDIT**: There is a bug in VS 2013 Update 2 RC that can cause this problem.  This NuGet package is supposed to fix the issue if you reference it in your Windows Phone app: [SuppressPackagingPclFacades](http://www.nuget.org/packages/SuppressPackagingPclFacades/).  Alternatively setting Copy Local to false for the reference from your PCL library to the PCL Storage assemblies should also fix the issue.

Comment: Still no go. I just tried putting a reference to FileSystem.Current in my App.xaml.cs and that too is failing with the same exception.

Comment: Any other ideas? I set copy local to false in the PCL project, and verified the path in the wp8 project = packages\PCLStorage.0.9.3\lib\wp8\PCLStorage.dll. Also went through and reinstalled the NuGet packages. And as I said above, it doesn't even work when used directly in my App.xaml.cs.

Comment: @earthling In your original question you say that it works OK if you start from a new WP8 project.  Is this correct?  One thing you can do is to open up the PCLStorage.dll that is getting included in the .xap file in a Reflector-like tool, and see if it includes implementations for WinRTFileSystem, WinRTFile, and WinRTFolder.

Comment: I observed the same thing in my project. Everything was working fine, then I installed the VS2013 Update 2 RC (For Windows Phone 8.1 development) - after this upgrade, I get the same problem as described above.

I "fixed" the problem by manually setting copy local=false on the PCLStorage.dll assembly in my PCL project

Comment: Same issue and fix for me as @espenalb with Xamarin.IOS, so doesn't appear to be specific to Windows Phone. Adding a link to the bug report: https://pclstorage.codeplex.com/workitem/10

Comment: @natecook Can you check if this NuGet package fixes the issue? http://www.nuget.org/packages/SuppressPackagingPclFacades/

Comment: @espenalb: Can you check if this NuGet package fixes the issue? http://www.nuget.org/packages/SuppressPackagingPclFacades/

Comment: Actually I'm not on VS2013 Update 2 (RC or otherwise). I am on VS 2013 Update 1. In any case SuppressPackagingPclFacades won't install because it's targeting an incompatible PCL profile: "You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-net45+win+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10', but the 
package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework."