# F# interactive throws NotImplementedException in PCLStorage

Tags: f#, portable-class-library, f#-interactive

I'm getting NotImplementedException trying to use `PCLStorage.FileSystem.Current` in F# interactive.

I downloaded PCLStorage with NuGet, right clicked on the reference and clicked "Send to F# interactive"

I'm working with VS2015 update 1, and I've re-installed the package as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052472/pclstorage-in-windows-phone-8)

How can I get PCLStorage to work in F# interactive?

```
--> Referenced 'C:\Users\amade\Documents\GitHub\audioExperiments\src\Audio\packages\PCLStorage.1.0.2\lib\portable-net45+wp8+wpa81+win8+monoandroid+monotouch+Xamarin.iOS+Xamarin.Mac\PCLStorage.dll'

> open PCLStorage;;
> PCLStorage.FileSystem.Current;;
> System.NotImplementedException: This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly.  You should reference the PCLStorage NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation.
   at PCLStorage.FileSystem.get_Current()
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0017>.$FSI_0017.main@()
Stopped due to error
```

Comment: Given your F# interactive is running in the full version of .NET you will require a library compiled to match that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PCL you've referenced is the one designed to target all platforms (Xamarin, Windows desktop, Windows phone etc). This dll is simply used as a means of defining all of the individual methods as part of the bait and switch PCL technique http://log.paulbetts.org/the-bait-and-switch-pcl-trick/ If you want to use the library with FSI then you'll need to add a specific reference to the appropriate platform's DLL. In this case you'll want to refer to the windows desktop version of the project which you downloaded from NuGet.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! Is the `#r` directive the right way to load Windows DLL into interactive window?